# How do I make an @Input property readonly in an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-components

How would I make this @Input property read only in an angular component?

`@Input() name: string;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use the readonly qualifier as below, between the @Input decorator and the name identifier.

`@Input() readonly name: string;`